# How can I show full array without double clicking?

Tags: ide, clion

When I am debugging and trying to see a large array, CLion shows only the first 50 elements. I need to double click to see the rest. Is there a way to increase this amount to about 1000 elements by default?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a registry value that controls the number of children shown by default as a workaround until we come up with some more convenient solution.

Open the registry (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Registry...) and set the `cidr.debugger.value.maxChildren` to the desired value.

From the related [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/05/clion-2017-2-eap-debugger-fixes/):

> While inspecting arrays during debug, you might notice there was a limit of 50 elements shown by default. To see more user had to explicitly expand the next 50 elements. This was done to reduce performance issues. However, sometimes a few elements with big indexes are needed, and it’s quite tiresome to click *expand* several times in a row.
>
> In order to provide a solution to the problem, we’ve added a registry value to control the default number of composite value’s children.
>
> [image: cidr.debugger.value.maxChildren]